# Touchpad detected but doesn't work (or almost) - Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, hp-touchpad

my touchpad suddenly stopped working, normally at least. The scrolling works (kinda, very chaotic), the left and right buttons work, but I can't move the pointer nor can I tap. When I open the touchpad settings, nothing abnormal appears to me. It seems detected.

When the laptop (hp ENVY DV6) is in sleep mode, it starts when I simply touch the touchpad, but later it doesn't respond at all (except the chaotic scrolling).

For a person who spends a lot of time on the computer, this is very annoying. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Edit: I tried to install Windows, and it works normally when I use the installation interface (I didn't complete the installation but whatever). I can move the pointer normally. So it's probably a software thing. Unfortunately, I don't know what else to do. Anyone? please?

Edit 2: I installed Lubuntu, completely this time, and at first it worked again normally, but after a few minutes, it turned back to the weird state (pointer not moving, only chaotic 2-finger scrolling). This is very strange and somewhat annoying. Please if you can help, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting steps you can try:

**Check Drivers:** Make sure your touchpad drivers are up-to-date. You can update your packages by running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

**Reset Touchpad Settings:** Go to your touchpad settings and reset all options to their default values.

**Test Another User:** Create a new user account and log in to see if the issue persists. This will help determine if the problem is user-specific.

**Check Hardware:** Try connecting an external mouse to see if the issue is indeed with the touchpad.

**Check System Logs:** Use the command `dmesg | grep -i "touchpad"` to check if there are any touchpad-related errors in the system logs.

**Restart Touchpad Service:** Use the command `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse` to restart the touchpad service.

**Check BIOS/UEFI Settings:** Sometimes, BIOS settings can affect the touchpad functionality. Make sure everything is configured correctly there.

Comment: I'm certainly not super-intelligent, but this is the first time I've been told that my intelligence is artificial ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot Benoît. I've tried AI (if that's what you mean, at least the suggestions were similar to yours). 
1) done
2) done
3) done
4) done (mouse works normally)
5) [system logs]

Comment: `[    3.674346] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1e5d SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    3.773542] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x26c00/0x0, board id: 2054, fw id: 1107342
[    3.839314] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4`
6) done
7) I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved, but I have no idea how.
Here's what I did: reinstalled Kubuntu 22.04, installed updates (I avoided that thinking they caused the malfunctions), restarted once, (all this time the problem persisted). Then restarted a seconde time. Then it works almost normally (it just won't allow me to toggle the "tap to click" option). I don't know, maybe in a few minutes it won't work anymore, but it's been over an hour now and it seems working just fine.